# How to change the items selectable in a paper-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a paper-menu that needs to change when a function is called.

The code I am using is below.

```
 var sessionHtml = "";
  for (var selector in selections) {
    selector = selectors[selector];
    selectorHtml = selectorHtml + "<paper-item>" + selector.name + "</paper-item>";
  }
  $(".menu").html(selectorHtml);
```

The function works on the page load, but will cause the menu to become unresponsive and not respond to an item being clicked if called afterwards. Is  there a function on paper-menu that can be called to update it or a different way to update the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new section around the paper-menu and changing the whole div. This seems to make polymer update the menu properly.

```
  var sessionHtml = "<paper-menu class='selector' selected='0'>";
  for (var selector in selections) {
    selector = selectors[selector];
    selectorHtml = selectorHtml + "<paper-item>" + selector.name + "</paper-item>";
  }
  $(".selector-container").html(sessionHtml + "</paper-menu>");
```